# How to exclude some item when query with typeorm in Nestjs and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to build a query when i send `username` to server so i can exclude the record has the excludeUsers has the same username i sent.
Here is my data : `

```
         "id": "f4830220-9912-4cbb-b685-edf4aaaf8fd5",
         "createdAt": "2022-03-24T10:19:48.096Z",
         "updatedAt": "2022-03-24T10:26:42.487Z",
         "isDeleted": false,
         "username": "vietphuongthoa98",
         "link": "",
         "type": "follow",
         "current": 13456,
         "target": 13556,
         "totalPurchase": 100,
         "purchasedPacks": [
             {
                 "id": "fbb3079b-32c9-4c4b-a297-16741d1f5485",
                 "name": "Some packets",
                 "type": "follow",
                 "count": 2,
                 "price": 100,
                 "follows": 50,
                 "createdAt": "2022-03-23T07:18:22.898Z",
                 "isDeleted": false,
                 "updatedAt": "2022-03-23T09:49:30.192Z",
                 "description": "Some packages description.",
                 "originPrice": 0
             }
         ],
         "excludeUsers": [
             {
                 "id": "9d8c25d2-8f03-46b3-92fa-b9489b943a56",
                 "deviceName": "iPhone 12 Pro Max",
                 "username": "hoaa.hanassii",
                 "platform": "ios",
                 "timeZone": 0,
                 "deviceAge": 21,
                 "subscribed": true,
                 "coins": 19600,
                 "subscriptionExpiration": "2022-04-27T00:00:00.000Z",
                 "isBlocked": false
             }
         ]
```

Here is my query builder :

```
queryBuilder
   .leftJoin('featured_user.excludeUsers', 'excludeUsers')
   .andWhere('excludeUsers.username != :username', {
     username: filter.username,
   });
```

The actual query result is :

```
SELECT "featured_user"."id" AS "featured_user_id",
   "featured_user"."tenant_id" AS "featured_user_tenant_id",
   "featured_user"."created_at" AS "featured_user_created_at",
   "featured_user"."updated_at" AS "featured_user_updated_at",
   "featured_user"."is_deleted" AS "featured_user_is_deleted",
   "featured_user"."username" AS "featured_user_username",
   "featured_user"."link" AS "featured_user_link",
   "featured_user"."type" AS "featured_user_type",
   "featured_user"."current" AS "featured_user_current",
   "featured_user"."target" AS "featured_user_target",
   "featured_user"."total_purchase" AS "featured_user_total_purchase",
   "featured_user"."purchased_packs" AS "featured_user_purchased_packs",
   "featured_user"."user_id" AS "featured_user_user_id",
   "excludeUsers"."username" AS "excludeUsers_username",
   "excludeUsers"."id" AS "excludeUsers_id"
FROM "featured_users" "featured_user"
LEFT JOIN "featured_users_exclude_users_users" "featured_user_excludeUsers" ON "featured_user_excludeUsers"."featured_users_id"="featured_user"."id"
LEFT JOIN "users" "excludeUsers" ON "excludeUsers"."id"="featured_user_excludeUsers"."users_id"
WHERE "excludeUsers"."username" != $1 -- PARAMETERS: ["hoaa.hanassii"]
```

The problem is nothing response. Any ideal ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you add getMany() end of querybuilder and try

```
 queryBuilder
   .leftJoin('featured_user.excludeUsers', 'excludeUsers')
   .andWhere('excludeUsers.username != :username', {
     username: filter.username,
   }).getMany()
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. I already have that in my code but it return nothing.

Comment: can you select only field which value must required. just to check if data is coming or not